# How does python flock() work?

Tags: python, flock

I have the following code:

```
import os, fcntl

f = open('./testfile.t', 'wb')
f.write(os.urandom(64))

fcntl.flock(f.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX)
print 'Locked'

try:
    f2 = open('./testfile.t', 'wb')
except IOError as err:
    print err.errno
    print err
```

The idea is that second `open` should return an error, because file is still locked.
The problem is it doesn't.
Moreover, if I try to acquire a lock on `f2.fileno()` this code just hangs up, instead of  throwing an exception.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: Flocking is *advisory*. It doesn't make the file inaccessible, it merely prevents others from getting a lock on it simultaneously. Both processes must cooperate in the flocking.

Comment: @deceze so it's even more unclear why I cannot acquire second lock on this file and the process just hangs up

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to acquire a second lock, and if there's already an exclusive lock on the file, that *perfectly* explains why you can't acquire a second one.